# Как вернуть значение из асинхронной функции?

Tags: javascript, функции, chrome-extension

Как правильно возвратить значение в этой функции ?

```js
function getValue(variable, defaultvalue) {
  chrome.storage.sync.get({
    [variable]: defaultvalue,
  }, function(items) {
    if (items[variable]) {
      return items[variable];
    }
  });
}
```

Вот так не получается,а если `return items[variable]` заменить на `alert(items[variable])` то успешно выводиться что нужно,а если с `return` то возвращает `undefined`.
Нужно чтобы при `alert(getValue('test', 'var'))` возвращалось то, что мне нужно, а не `undefined` .

Comment: Советую ближе познакомится с такой актуальной темой как асинхронность в Javascript.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Так как в данном случае функция `getValue` ничего не возвращает, то результат выполнения

```
getValue(variable, defaultvalue)
```

всегда будет `undefined`.

Возможные пути решения:

1. Пробросить `callback` - функцию, которая будет вызвана при успешном выполнении, например

   ```
   function getValue(variable, defaultvalue, successCallback) {
     chrome.storage.sync.get({
       [variable]: defaultvalue,
     }, function(items) {
       if (items[variable]) {
         successCallback(items[variable]);//вызываем callback если все хорошо
       }
     });
   }
   ```

   И вызывать ее следующим образом:

   ```
   getValue(variable, defaultvalue, function(items){//items внутри этой функции - будут нужным значением
       ... 
   })
   ```
2. Можно использовать `Promise`, например так:

   ```
   function getValue(variable, defaultvalue, successCallback) {
       return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
           chrome.storage.sync.get({
               [variable]: defaultvalue,
           }, function(items) {
               if (items[variable]) {
                   resolve(items[variable]);//говорим что все хорошо
               }else{
                   reject(/*тут можно указать причину почему все плохо*/);
               }
           });

       });
   }
   ```

   И использовать так

   ```
   getValue(variable, defaultvalue).then(function success(items){//items внутри этой функции - будут нужным значением
       ... 
   });
   ```

Comment: Вопрос знатокам -  в чем разница между вариантами 1 и 2?

Comment: @Darth, вложенные коллбеки смотрятся намного хуже чем цепочка вызовов, особенно если их много