# Как в Первой функции получить результат выполнения Второй?

Tags: javascript, функции

Всем привет! Подскажите, пожалуйста, у меня две функции: Первая формирует данные и передаёт их во Вторую, которая отправляет их на сервер.

**Как мне в Первой функции получить результат выполнения второй?**

```
// Первая функция в которой формируются данные для сервера
function A() {

  // код

  // проверяем ответ из Второй функции
  if (xhr(url, data) == 2) {
    console.log('okay');
  } else {
    console.log('mistake');
    console.log(xhr(url, data));
  }
}

// Вторая функция, которая отправляет данные на сервер
function B(url, date) {

  // код

  // отправляем данные на сервер
  request.send(data);

  // проверяем ответ сервера
  request.onload = function() {

    if (request.status >= 200 && request.status < 400) {

      // если отправили, то php на сервере отвечает ok
      if (request.responseText == 'ok') {
        return 2;
        console.log(2);

      // если не отправили
      } else {
        return 4;
        console.log(4);

      // если статус ответа < 200 или > 400
      } else {
        return 4.1;
        console.log(4.1);
      }
   }
}
```

Для теста я расставил console.log. Результат выполнения кода получается такой:

- данные отправляются на сервер, php отрабатывает и всё отправляет
- function А выводит в консоль mistake и `undefined` (undefined из console.log(xhr(url, data))
- function B выводит в консоль «2» (request.responseText == 'ok')

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне вывести результаты ответа отправки сообщения?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из асинхронной функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/513037/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8)

Answer (score 0):

У вас пропущена закрывающая фигурная скобка в функции В. Так же стоит в функции А присвоить в переменную результат работы функции В и потом проверять. А то, у вас получается два вызова В, а значит и два запроса к серверу и ответ может оказаться разным.

Comment: Да, спасибо, ссылку пропустил из-за сложного форматирования на этом сайте. 

Присваивание функции при проверке не решает проблему (не спорю, что так лучше). Думаю, дело действительно в асинхронности, как дали ссылку выше, но это для меня сложновато. Придётся пока объединить две функции в одну.